# How can I see what library owns symbols for an lldb backtrace

Tags: c, macos, lldb

I am trying to debug an EXC_BAD_ACCESS but can't tell what was executed using backtrace with lldb. Of course I am missing the debug symbols for those particular frames but I don't know how to figure out what library owns the address. I tried image list --address with the address of the stack frame but that doesn't return anything. Any pointers (no pun intended) would be greatly appreciated. My end goals is to hopefully see the line of code where the the segfault happened. I am doing this from command line and not from xcode btw.

Here is a snapshot of my stacktrace with the missing symbols in case my explanation wasn't making sense.

```
frame #0: 0x0000000103f7e2dc
frame #1: 0x0000000103f5c3d0
frame #2: 0x0000000103f5c2b3
frame #3: 0x0000000103f5c2b3
frame #4: 0x0000000103f5c2b3
frame #5: 0x0000000103f5c2b3
frame #6: 0x0000000103f5c0d8
frame #7: 0x0000000103f564e7
frame #8: 0x00000001036d6d90 libjvm.dylib`JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 554
frame #9: 0x00000001036d6b60 libjvm.dylib`JavaCalls::call(JavaValue*, methodHandle, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 40
frame #10: 0x0000000103860580 libjvm.dylib`Reflection::invoke(instanceKlassHandle, methodHandle, Handle, bool, objArrayHandle, BasicType, objArrayHandle, bool, Thread*) + 2556
frame #11: 0x00000001038609e6 libjvm.dylib`Reflection::invoke_method(oopDesc*, Handle, objArrayHandle, Thread*) + 366
frame #12: 0x00000001037236d7 libjvm.dylib`JVM_InvokeMethod + 358
frame #13: 0x0000000103f6e4b9
frame #14: 0x0000000103f5c2b3
frame #15: 0x0000000103f5c2b3
frame #16: 0x0000000103f5c961
frame #17: 0x0000000103f5c2b3
frame #18: 0x0000000103f5c2b3
frame #19: 0x0000000103f5c2b3
frame #20: 0x0000000103f5c2b3
frame #21: 0x0000000103f5c0d8
frame #22: 0x0000000103f5c0d8
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the name of the library stands next to the address. Since your backtrace shows libjvm, I guess that the frames without further information are JIT-compiled Java code.

Comment: Yes, it is a jni app that I have been working on but the instruction has to come from somewhere? There has to be some stripped library that is missing, but I don't know where to look. The frame address is the same  0x0000000103f7e2dc every time which makes me think it is located in some dylib and is not a dynamic address being created is say like a jit casche? I am a really a java programmer with a little c experience so I may be completely off base with my assumptions.